# Networking with Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-networking

I wanted to ask a question about general reliability and performance, when making network requests in fragments
I have a number of fragments, in which I make network requests to a server for data. Each fragments handles the networking separately.

Would it be better that I create a base fragment which all of my other fragments extend, making it so that the base fragment handles the heavy lifting (network requests) or let each handle its own? Thank you!

Comment: Personally I design Fragments to just be "intelligent" views but in relative terms they're quite "dumb". In other words, anything like network downloads are handled by the Activity they're attached to or I often use an IntentService for network operations.

Comment: @Squonk Even when you are calling login web service ? if so how ? can you please explain. *curious to know*

Comment: @TGMCians : If I'm using a web login system with Fragments, I'd use a simple Fragment with username/password EditTexts and a "Login" Button. Clicking the Button would call a 'callback' interface method implemented by the Activity (passing the username/password) and the Activity would do whatever is necessary - either using an AsyncTask or IntentService etc Assuming the login is successful, the Activity can maintain any login 'state' (session id, auth token etc) and any other Fragment can communicate its network needs via the Activity through to the web service.

Comment: @Squonk Nice approach. I like it. Can you please share a bit code of it in answer ? it will help op also

Comment: @Squonk intent service seems like the way to go, but wouldn't I have to have multiple receivers? I.e for each fragment?

Comment: @Aashir : It's a broad subject and depends on what each network operation might be (login, file download or upload etc). The design approach for Fragments should be they're self-contained and reusable. All communication should be done from Fragment <-> Activity so if you use an IntentService get the Fragment to tell the Activity to start the IntentService via an interface and the Activity can receive the result and pass it back to the Fragment through a public method in the Fragment itself. Sorry I can't post example code at the moment but will put up a basic example later today.

Comment: I disagree with @Squonk. It really depends on network operations you're using. If each fragment has a unique operation that is only relevant to that fragment its better if you keep it inside fragment. (OOP "encapsulation" principle) But if your code is mainly similar and it can be done all in one place, put it in activity or some other class and use it in activity. (OOP "code reuse" principle)  
Copying the same code over and over again is not a good habit and you should avoid that in any way you can unless there is a good reason for not doing so! like when reusing makes code more complicated)

Comment: @ Squonk its for downloading data (json etc). Also, I see where you're going with this. But about using the Activity, in my case, it already has to handle multiple callbacks for the UI and auth. Anyway, I'll look into intent service, Thanks!. @Alireza as I mentioned, it's for downloading and yes, the code used in the fragments is very similar. When you say that it should be pit into one place, would creating a base fragment and then extending from it help? (as in the question).

Comment: Yes it's a valid solution But you still have multiple connections! You improve the code by reusing but it has nothing to do with performance and reliability because when you create a new class you create a new instance of that class and also new instance of every parent of it!
I'm not sure having one connection improves the performance or not! In oppos i think multi connection may even improve performance since they run in parallel. Anyway if you want to have only one connection you should think about another solution